# h2o random forest calculating MSE for multinomial classification

Tags: classification, random-forest, multinomial, h2o

Why is `h2o.randomforest` calculating MSE on Out of bag sample and while training for a multinomail classification problem?

I have done binary classification also using h2o.randomforest, there it used to calculate `AUC` on `out of bag sample` and while `training` but for multi classification random forest is calculating MSE which seems suspicious. Please see this screenshot.

[image]

My target variable was a factor containing 4 factor levels `model1`, `model2`, `model3` and `model4`. In the screenshot you would also a confusion matrix for these factors.

Can someone please explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Both binomial and multinomial classification display MSE, so you will see it in the Scoring History table for both models (highlighted training_MSE column).

H2O does not evaluate a multinomial AUC. A few evaluation methods exist, but there is not yet a single widely adopted method. The [pROC package](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/pROC/docs/multiclass.roc) discusses the method of Hand and Till, but mentions that it cannot be plotted and results rarely tested. Log loss and classification error are still available, specific to classification, as each has standard methods of evaluation in a multinomial context.

There is a confusion matrix comparing your 4 factor levels, as you highlighted. Can you clarify what more you are expecting? If you were looking for four individual confusion matrices, the four-column table contains enough information that they could be computed.